# What is "Chrome Client" in relation to WebKit?

Tags: webkit

The WebKit source code and documentation uses the term "Chrome Client" often to describe a certain class used for front-end display.  I'm confused by what the term "Chrome" refers to, as it seems to be unrelated to the Google Chromium port.  It's difficult to search for any information about this on the web, because the search terms "chrome" and "client" inevitably bring up [results](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=webkit+chrome+client&oq=webkit+chrome+client&gs_l=serp.3...1371.1371.0.1512.1.1.0.0.0.0.51.51.1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.lmD0Sj12Y1w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=a808cb29d0b3169b&bpcl=40096503&biw=1444&bih=989) relating to the Google Chrome browser, or merely give me links to the WebKit source code.

Can anyone explain what Chrome Client is, and what "Chrome" means in this context?

Comment: "Chrome" is often used to describe any user interface element not derived from the page the user is visiting (as in, provided by the browser program itself).  For a more specific explanation, maybe you can provide a link to one of the places you've seen the term used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ChromeClient`](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/page/ChromeClient.h?rev=140260#L89) is an abstract interface that WebCore uses to interact with the multiple WebKit API layers that are built on top of WebCore. Its functionality centers around the user interface (aka "chrome") aspects of the view containing a particular WebCore `Page`. This abstraction is important as there are a number of separate API layers built on top of WebCore, and how each API layer handles the user interface can differ even between API layers running on the same OS (for instance, WebKit and WebKit2 have quite different needs).

As a simple example, `ChromeClient::runJavaScriptAlert` is called by the JavaScript `alert` function. The implementation of [`runJavaScriptAlert` for the Cocoa `WebView` class](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit/mac/WebCoreSupport/WebChromeClient.mm?rev=140260#L430) simply calls in to the appropriate `WebUIDelegate` methods as one would expect. Other cases, such as the display of tooltips, are handled entirely by the concrete `ChromeClient` implementation directly without involving any of `WebView`'s delegates.

Answer (score 1):

ChomeClient is a interface which delegates displaying GUI elements like alert, popup window, prompt, window(window.open) to WebKit ports.

Basically we can say window related operations like scrolling, requesting repaint via invalidating portion of window,..etc

Each WebKit port provides their own implementation by overriding the ChromeClient interaface. For example Qt might have ChromeClientQt.h & ChromeClientQt.cpp & GTK might have ChromeClientGTk.h & ChromeClientGTk.cpp.

Comment: Can I know why -1? is it completely irrelevant? Is it more irrelevant than the previous author's comment?

Answer (score -1):

Webkit is a web browser rendering rendering engine used by Safari and Chrome (among others, but these are the popular ones).

The -webkit prefix on CSS selectors are properties that only this engine is intended to process, very similar to -moz properties. Many of us are hoping this goes away, for example -webkit-border-radius will be replaced by the standard border-radius and you won't need multiple rules for the same thing for multiple browsers. This is really the result of "pre-specification" features that are intended to not interfere with the standard version when it comes about.

For your update:...no it's not related to IE really, IE at least before 9 uses a different rendering engine called Trident.